# woocommerce product image hook and notification hook actions

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, hook

In my woocommerce shop I need to fix two things but I'm not sure how to proceed.

1) I have noticed that the woocommerce notifications will appear covered by the main navbar of the site that is transprent until the user start scroll the page, I need to put it in a more visible place like under the navbar. I'm not sure if there is an hook and how I can let it bootstrap 4 friendly.

2) The single product images that are displayed when an user click on a product to see the details are too big and I don't know what hook to use to modify it to give a size that will fit on the left part where it's displayed, now the user need to scroll the page to see the image.

Can anyone help me to fix there issue? 
[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. I couldn't understand what you are trying to say. Can you share the URL of the site which you're referring to?
2. Image sizes of a detailed product page can now be under the Customizer.

```
 Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images
```

[image]

Comment: I've read the docs about this but I need to add bootstrap class to the image, this will only set the size of the image

Comment: Moreover the customizer solution will not work, the scroll to see the full product image will remain.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the product page?

Comment: It's on my localhost for now. I've applied various bootstrap classes to the default woocommerce templates, I think the problem is this?

Comment: I can't really come to a conclusion without seeing the code. Can you share the screenshot of the product page?

Comment: see the image, can you now understand what I mean? The image size is too big and will require that the user scroll the page to see it entirely. NB: I've already set the dimension inside the customizer, but it's unuseful.

Comment: If you set a size for product image under Customizer then it should work. May I know the size of the image? Are you saying that you want to use a too big image but it should display within the first screen? I am not able to get an idea about the site as i didnt see the code.